# How to override preference page store method in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I created an Eclipse preference page which has to String fields: one for user and one for password.

I want to override the method that stores this in .prefs files and I want to use ISecurePreferences to store the password in an encrypted form.

When I override performApply() method I'm expecting the method only to display the message inside it:

```
@Override
protected void performApply() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    System.out.println("Perfom apply");     
}
```

Unfortunately, Eclipse still stores the preferences in its own way.

I can't find the method that acctually stores the preferences in Eclipse.

Can you tell me where is this done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`performApply` is only called when you press the `Apply` button.

`performOk` is called when the `OK` button is pressed so override that. The default for `performApply` is just to call `performOk` so you don't need to override that as well.